# The Galois Field for the polynomial $x^3 - 2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I am reading a textbook prior to taking my first course in Field Theory. I think that if someone could answer the following 4 questions simply as True of False I might be less confused.  I am denoting the 3rd root of unity as $\zeta_3$.

1) Does $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ contain ALL the roots of the polynomial  $x^3 - 2$?
2) Does $\mathbb Q(\zeta_3\sqrt[3]2)$ contain ALL the roots of the polynomial  $x^3 - 2$?
3) Does $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,\zeta_3)$ contain ALL the roots of the polynomial $x^3 - 2$?
4) Is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,\zeta_3)$ the SMALLEST field that contains ALL the roots of the polynomial $x^3 - 2$?

If the answers are False, False, True, True respectively then I think I am OK.  Otherwise some gentle explanation would help me.

Comment: Your answers are correct :)

Comment: OK Thanks.  One more True/False question might also help me.  The fields described in question 1) and question 2) above are certainly not equal as sets but they ARE isomorphic as fields.

Comment: Hmmm something a bit unrelated, but a little tricky. Is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2) \cong \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$?

Comment: @CuddyCuttlefish .$F_1=Q(\sqrt 2)$ and $ F_2=Q(\sqrt 3)$ are not isomorphic. An isomorphism $\psi :F_1\to F_2$ would satisfy $\psi (2)=2$ but then $\psi(\sqrt 2)=\pm \sqrt 2\in F_2$. But $ \sqrt (2)\notin F_2.$

Comment: I will guess that they are not isomorphic but my guess is only based on the fact that the "obvious"  isomorphism i.e., a + b*Sqrt(2)  -> a + b*Sqrt(3) doesn't preserve multiplication.  Otherwise, I do not know how to prove this.

Comment: @user254665  Why does the value of an isomorphism at Sqrt(2) have to equal Sqrt(2) or - Sqrt(2) ?

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer . $0=\psi (0)=\psi ((\sqrt 2)^2-2)=(\psi (\sqrt 2))^2+\psi (-2)=(\psi (\sqrt 2))^2-2.$